# Import Ruby project from GitHub

Tags: ruby, eclipse, github

Does any body know how to import a Ruby project hosted on GitHub inside Eclipse?

I want to import the [popHealth GitHub Project](https://github.com/pophealth/popHealth). When I do this I get an error:

```
network connection ssh2 eclipse preferences
```

I installed it via:

```
  sudo apt-get install openssh Server
```

Comment: I don't think the `ruby` tag is too appropriate.

Comment: It will be better if you help me rather than pointing finger towards which TAG is appropriate and which is not?

Comment: I just commented in order to help you, if you use the right tags you'd have more chances someone answered this. Also, I tried to correct your english in order to help you.

Comment: have you try `git clone https://github.com/pophealth/popHealth.git`?